# Spring boot controller path giving 404 on websphere 9

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-9

I have a spring boot 2.0 application that is working fine on embedded tomcat , now I generated a war from this applcation using `apply plugin: 'war'` in build.gradle file , the war is generated and deployed successfully on websphere 9 ... I tried hitting the context root, it gives the index.html correctly ... but when try to reach any path that was originally reached on the embedded tomcat it gives `Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /path/mapped/in/controller` ... can any one tell what is missing ?

this is the SpringBootApplication class code :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan(basePackages = { "com.mypack.dao" })
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, do you resolve this issue? I faced the same..

Comment: The issue was mainly with the websphere server that I downloaded, the server needs dll and exe to run, the company firewall blocked their download, so the servlet container was not working